# JQuery validation working individually but not together

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

****EDIT*****
i tried it with && instead of || and now it does not come back as false for any file.  I do think it needs to be && though.

I have a custom validation function that I am using to check if the file is an excel file.  When i test is the last 4 characters are .xls OR the last 5 characters are .xlsx it works but when i check for both it does not.  Any idea why it will not let me do this?

```
$.validator.addMethod("xlsxOrxls", function(value, element) {
    var isValid = true;
    var xlsx = value.substr(value.length - 5);
    var xls = value.substr(value.length - 4);
    if (xls != '.xls' || xlsx != '.xlsx') 
        isValid = false;
    return isValid;
}, "<br/><label style='color:red'><b>Not a valid file format.</b></label>"
);
```

If I comment out the var xlsx line and take out the "|| xlsx != '.xlsx'" part of the if statement it works and vice versa, but if i leave them both in there it will not work.  I have even tried making them 2 separate functions but thats not working either.

Any idea why its not letting me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex instead!

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "xlsxOrxls",
    function(value, element) {
        return value.match(/\.xlsx?$/);
    },
    "<br/><label style='color:red'><b>Not a valid file format.</b></label>"
);
```

Or, if you really want do do it your way:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "xlsxOrxls",
    function(value, element) {
        var xlsx = value.substr(value.length - 5);
        var xls = value.substr(value.length - 4);
        return xls == '.xls' || xlsx == '.xlsx';
    },
    "<br/><label style='color:red'><b>Not a valid file format.</b></label>"
);
```

Comment: Thanks, i used the second way and it worked how i needed it to.  Are there benefits to regex over "my way"?

Comment: It's shorter, and easier to read. You don't have to remember where substr counts from, etc. A more readable form would be `value.match(/\.(xls|xslx|more|file|extensions|here)$/);`. That would be much harder to write your way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for &&, not ||. if the extension is different from .xls and its also different from .xlsx, then isValid is false.

Comment: Yeah i tried && right after and now it doesnt show an error message for any file type.  I made an edit to my above post.

Answer (score 0):

You've got mutually exclusive conditions, but you're trying to check both of them at once. If the last 5 characters is ".xlsx" then the last 4 will never be ".xls" and vice versa.

Check for one condition and if it doesn't pass, check the other.

Comment: Thanks, i realized that "OR" wasnt the right way to go a little after i posted it

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for Validation on `xls` and `xlsx` type files. I tried this easiest & simplest way..

```
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

### Valid Accept Types:

For **CSV** files (.csv), use:

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" />
```

For **Excel Files 2003-2007** (.xls), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

For **Excel Files 2010** (.xlsx), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

For **Text Files** (.txt) use:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/plain" />
```

For **Image Files** (.png/.jpg/etc), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

For **HTML Files** (.htm,.html), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/html" />
```

For **Video Files** (.avi, .mpg, .mpeg, .mp4), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" />
```

For **Audio Files** (.mp3, .wav, etc), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*" />
```

For **PDF Files**, use:

```
<input type="file" accept=".pdf" />
```

reference from Dom's Answer